# Angular material input font size changes if it's inside a mat-card-content

Tags: angular, angular-material

> I have an issue using `@angular/material` `<mat-card-content/>` and input
>   since the `matInput` has `font-size: inherit` when I place it inside
>   `<mat-card-content/>` the font size of the input changes to 14px when is
>   outside of this component is 16px here is an exaple. Is this intended
>   or it's a bug ? Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wesaav?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: The `font-size` of `matInput` is `14px` inside the `mat-card` seems intended as the overall font-size of card content is only `14px`

Comment: No it seems they have a bug logged with this was just harder to find

Comment: If you think its a bug. Please raise an issue on GitHub.

Comment: It's already logged I found it on github

Answer (score 1):

It is generally expected that you apply `.mat-typography` to your application's outer most element or the page `body` in order to implement the correct font size, weight, etc. for various elements including standard HTML elements like `<p>` and `<div>`. If you do this, the default font size becomes 14px so it will match `.mat-card-content`.

I logged this as a bug years ago but they ignored it. At the time, Material Design specifications had a fixed font size for inputs (14px) but the Angular Material people still thought it was best to implement it with size as `inherit`. It can cause a lot of issues even when you use `.mat-typography` if you want to use inputs in places other than typical forms such as on a toolbar. IMO they really goofed with this.